# Tooltip width in the middle of the text

Tags: width, tooltip

is there any way to force this tooltip span to full width of the text?  I have left it visible for your convenience. Thank you in advance.

http://test.fusionidea.com/cane5/why.html

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, this should be the answer:

```
white-space: nowrap; //add this to class popup-div
```

But as your text is really long, this will make the popup not usable.
Maybe you want to set the width for the popup div as well.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

add this styles

```
.popup-div{ 
    width: 100%;
}
```

and remove this

```
a.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In this way the tooltip will loose his position, he needs to stay above "CANE founders Carrie & Amy" and if i remove position:relative of that tag it will go down. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: other way, add .popup-div{ width: 360px; }